# Camel with JMS Transaction and REST post call

Tags: java, apache-camel

I need to read a message from a queue and call a REST service doing a post.

Then, I was looking about the JMS transaction with Camel, it looks like you can set a `maximumRedeliveries` to process the queue message again, so rolling back the transaction in case of a failure, I was wondering how it can work if in the same camel route we have to call a REST service to post something, how that part can be rollback??

maxDelivery conf:

```
errorHandler(new TransactionErrorHandlerBuilder()
        .loggingLevel(LoggingLevel.ERROR)
        .useOriginalMessage()
        .maximumRedeliveries(2)
        .logHandled(false)
        .logExhausted(true)
    );
```

Pseudo code for the route:

```
//Reading message from the queue
from("activemq:AMQ.App.EMC2.In.PMQueue?jmsMessageType=Bytes").
    transacted().
    unmarshal(jaxbDataFormat).bean(pmMessageEnricher).
    to("direct:start-post");

//Then doing the post
from("direct:start-post").
    setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST")).
    setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json")).
    setBody(constant(pmMessageEnricher.toJson())).
    to("http://xxx").
    to("direct:start-somethingelse");

//Then doing something else
from("direct:start-somethingelse").
blabla...
```

Let say an exception occurs in the `start-somethingelse`, How the REST post call can be roll backed ? since we call an external service in a stateless way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your doubt is correct. In case of a JMS transaction rollback, the POST request **cannot be rolled back** because the service provider is **not part of the JMS transaction**. The transaction is just between the JMS broker and the Camel JMS consumer (see also [Camel transactional client](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/transactional-client.adoc)).

However, if you catch the processing error, you can **apply the needed compensation logic**. For example delete the already posted data with another request.

By the way: **don't confuse Camel redeliveries and broker redeliveries!**

Camel redeliveries are done by the [Camel Errorhandler](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/user-manual/en/error-handler.adoc) (not the broker). In your example it does up to 2 redeliveries. But be aware, that *Camel redeliveries are not reprocessing the entire route, but only the failed processor*.

So if `to("http://xxx")` fails and the Camel Errorhandler does redeliveries, Camel retries only the `to("http://xxx")`.

In contrast, *if your JMS transaction is rolled back, the broker redelivers the message to Camel and the entire route is processed again*.

**Take care that you don't "mask" the JMS redelivery with your Camel Errorhandler.**

Comment: Good amount of details here. You might also consider linking the official documentation on [transactional clients](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/transactional-client.adoc) and/or on [error handlers](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/user-manual/en/error-handler.adoc)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I added the links

Comment: i found something else about the redelivery (coming from this very useful link): "The redelivery in transacted mode is not handled by Camel but by the backing system (the transaction manager). In such cases you should resort to the backing system how to configure the redelivery" meaning if i have a transaction manager set with activeMq, and if I set my route and sub routes associated with .transacted(), the  .maximumRedeliveries(2) is pointless, the redeliveries max count is coming from the activemq broker